# Looking for .NET Heat Map API / SDK

Tags: geoprocessing, .net, heat-map

I have a requirement to add a 'heat map' style layer to a Javascript/jQuery based application that I am working on.  So far, I have used [heatmap.js](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/) with no problems at all.

My only concern with this approach is with how well it will handle a large number of points. I have asked for some type of upper bound, and the answer I got was 'a-lot', most likely going to be in the thousands.

So I am thinking I may try to create a WMS style web service - where a bounding box, image height & width are the request parameters, the server queries the points and does the rendering, and the resultant image sent back to client.

Does anyone know any such open source apis/sdks that contain this functionality?  I know such tools exist in qgis and arcgis desktop - but i am looking to do this in a service.

Comment: Is the heatmap static or does it have to be recreated on each request?